# Wrong value for ir.ui.menu.action on view side

Tags: odoo-view, odoo-13

i am new odoo dev. current i created new a model view and menu action i am not geting Error in model 
my custom modules work without a view when enabling view then occurred Error

model

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    partner_firstname = fields.Char(string="Partner Firstname")
```

View code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="res_pr_forms" model="ir.ui.view">
           <field name="name">resPatientforms</field>
           <field name="model">res.partner</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form >
                   <sheet>
                       <group>
                           <field name="partner_firstname"/>
                       </group>
                   </sheet>
               </form>
           </field>
       </record>


        <!-- This Menu Item will appear in the Upper bar, That's why It needs NO parent or action -->
        <menuitem id="test_view_root" name="Test yvonne "  />
        <!-- This Menu Item must have a parent and an action -->
        <menuitem id="test_sub_categ" name="Test form Open" parent="test_view_root" action="res_pr_forms" sequence="15"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Error

> ValueError: Wrong value for ir.ui.menu.action: 'form,765'
>
> raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %r" % (self, value))
>   odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Wrong value for ir.ui.menu.action: 'form,765'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a valid action (`ir.actions.act_window`) to the menu item, not a form view (`ir.ui.view`).

Check the following example taken from [Building a module/Actions and Menus](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html#actions-and-menus):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>

        <!-- window action -->
        <!--
            The following tag is an action definition for a "window action",
            that is an action opening a view or a set of views
        -->
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">   <!-- Action definition -->
            <field name="name">Courses</field>
            <field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">Create the first course
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- top level menu: no parent -->
        <menuitem id="main_openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"/>
        <!-- A first level in the left side menu is needed
             before using action= attribute -->
        <menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"
                  parent="main_openacademy_menu"/>
        <!-- the following menuitem should appear *after*
             its parent openacademy_menu and *after* its
             action course_list_action -->
        <menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Courses" parent="openacademy_menu"
                  action="course_list_action"/>                           <!-- specify the ation -->
        <!-- Full id location:
             action="openacademy.course_list_action"
             It is not required when it is the same module -->

</odoo>
```

Comment: I check the document with odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/actions.html still, I am confused about action what action I need to use relatively

Comment: You need to define an action to use it with the menu item (or use an existing one)[`<menuitem id=... action=" the id of the action"` **"course_list_action" in my example**], then define `form`, `tree`, ...  views using the same model.